# Angular 14 input file (change) not firing

Tags: typescript, angular14

In my HTML:

```
<input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)">
```

In my controller:

```
uploadFile(event: any) {
    const file: File = event.target.files[0];
}
```

When the page appears, the input is visible with the button "browse". When clicking the "browse" button, the default OS's file chooser pops up. So far so good. However, when selecting a file, the method uploadFile is never activated.
Note 1: when I add (click)="resetFile()" to the input tag, the method resetFile is indeed being called; just not the uploadFile method.
Note 2: I've seen many of these questions on a variety of sites but they all complained about the event not firing upon selecting the same file a second time. Here, it will not fire even upon selecting the file the first time.

Any help will be appreciated